# Proof Question Help

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are nonempty bounded subsets of $\mathbb R$ with $A \cap B = \emptyset$. 
>   Prove $\sup \, (A \cup B) \geq \max \, \{ \sup A,\sup B\}$.

So I thought for this proof it was enough to show that the $\sup \, (A \cup B)$ is an upper bound for the maximum of the two individual $\sup$'s.

But my professor's work starts off as "It suffices to show that, for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $x$ in $A \cup B$ such that $x> \max \, \{\sup A,\sup B \} - \epsilon$."

Why do we need to choose an arbitrary epsilon?

Comment: Basically they are using this fact: $\sup S \ge m$ if and only if any number strictly less than $m$ is **not** an upper bound of $S$. Can you see why this is true (remember that $\sup S$ is the *least* upper bound of $S$)? Note also that you can restate this as: $\sup S < m$ if and only if there exists a number $m' < m$ such that $m'$ is an upper bound of $S$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth While your comment address the general approach to the proof, it doesn't address the specific question - why do we need to use an arbitrary epsilon in our proof? We don't! One could easily proof this just as easily via contradiction without invoking any arbitrary epsilons. It just so happens that the professor decided to use this type of argument, but it isn't needed. Suppose WLOG that $\sup A > \sup B$. Then, if $\sup(A\cup B) < \sup A$, $\sup(A\cup B)$ is not an upper bounded for $A$, so there must be $x \in A$ such that

Comment: $\sup(A\cup B) < x < sup A$. But $x \in A\cup B$, so we have an element of $A \cup B$ greater than $\sup(A\cup B)$, a contradiction.

Comment: OK, I interpreted the question as why do we need to use an arbitrary $\epsilon$ in this approach to the proof. I will probably delete my comments later if that is preferred.